# Codemirror javascript indentation issue

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using `Codemirror` editor with `javascript` mode
`Javascript` mode indentation works fine except at one place.

When I hit enter when a cursor is before a closing bracket, indentation does not work.

```
function myFunction(){
}
```

The cursor stays right before the closing bracket.
Please help

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you're placing the cursor where the "|" is in this code:

```
function myFunction() {|}
```

...and pressing Enter.  I'm guessing you're expecting something more like this?

```
function myFunction() {
    |
}
```

That's not the CodeMirror default behavior, but you could write a fairly simple add-on to change that. Here's a rough starter:

```
CodeMirror.defineInitHook(function (codeMirror) {
    codeMirror.addKeyMap({
        name: "fixEnterWithinBraces",
        Enter: function (codeMirror) {
            if (codeMirror.somethingSelected()) return CodeMirror.Pass;

            var cursorPos = codeMirror.getCursor();
            var line = codeMirror.getLine(cursorPos.line);
            if (line.substr(cursorPos.ch - 1, 2) === "{}") {
                codeMirror.replaceRange("\n\n", cursorPos);
                codeMirror.setCursor(cursorPos.line + 1, 0);
                codeMirror.indentLine(cursorPos.line + 1);
            } else {
                return CodeMirror.Pass;
            }
        }
    });
});
```